limit condition implies finite n th moment for random variable

Problem. Given a random variable $X$, there exists a constant $a>1$ which satisfies $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\mathbb{P}(|X|>an)}{\mathbb{P}(|X|>n)} = 0,$$
prove that $\mathbb{E}(X^p)$ is finite for all $p$.

My attempt: by the well-known identity we have $$\mathbb{E}(|X|^p) = \int_0^\infty pn^{p-1}\mathbb{P}(|X|>n)\mathrm{d} n.$$ Replacing $n$ with $an$ we obtain $$\mathbb{E}(|X|^p) = \int_0^\infty pa^pn^{p-1}\mathbb{P}(|X|>an)\mathrm{d} n.$$ Hence we have $$(a^p -1)\mathbb{E}(|X|^p) = pa^p\int_0^\infty n^{p-1}\Big(\mathbb{P}(|X|>n) - \mathbb{P}(|X|>an)\Big)\mathrm{d} n.$$ And I'm stuck here. So I think perhaps I can solve the problem by doing a typical "$\int_0^\infty \leqslant \int_0^N + \int_N^\infty$" estimation, but I haven't figured it out :(

We can use a similar criterion as the one you mention for integrability of $\lvert X\rvert^p$:
$$
\mathbb E\left[\lvert X\rvert^p\right]<\infty\Leftrightarrow \sum_{k=1}^\infty a^{kp}\mathbb P\left(\lvert X\rvert>a^k\right).
$$
Use the ratio test for the convergence of the series.
